# (java)Detecting carriage return in a InputStream cast to char

Tags: java, inputstream

So I'm writing a program that gets input from a serial port.
 Like so:

```
String p = "COM3";

    SerialPort in = SerialPort.getCommPort(p);
    in.openPort();

    InputStream d = in.getInputStream();
```

To read the data from the port.stream I used the following piece of code

```
          do
            {
                System.out.print((char)d.read());
                counter++;

            }while(counter < 303);
```

fyi: The data from the Serial Port is coming from a Barcode Scanner, purpose of the program is to scan Drivers' Licenses.

The data is legible and everything, but it appears that the stream has carriage return or new line characters somewhere in it, resulting in the data being sectioned off into new lines, which is fine, but I wanna know how to detect these characters so that I can parse each new line/carriage return into a String/String Array entry. I did some searching but I can't find the answer I'm looking for.

I also tried outputting the stream to a .txt file and its not helping much. When you open the file in notepad, the stream data appears as one line. However in my file explorer preview screen, the data shows the way it does in my console, each piece of separate data has its own line.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Given that you have a **char someChar = (char) d.read()** then your only best bet to detect a carriage return would be to check **if(someChar == '\r')** (CR=CARRIAGE_RETURN_CHARACTER) or **if(someChar == '\n')** (NL=NEWLINE_CHARACTER)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 characters you need to look for: new line `\n` and carriage return `\r`.

```
char next = (char)d.read();
if(next == '\r') {
    System.out.print("\\r");
} else if(char == '\n') {
    System.out.print("\\n");
} else {
    System.out.print(next);
}
```

You have to escape the back slash or it will actually print a new line/carriage return and break up the text, when you really want it to just print `\r` or `\n`. If you have to read this back in later, you will need to account for that fact that it takes 2 characters to represent these in text.